# access session variable during 2nd request to server

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on creating a csv file in php. The call will be initiated using ajax. If there are more rows then csv file creation can take more time. Meanwhile I try to stop the creation using a cancel by initiating another ajax request. My initial code for creating csv file was:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
{ 
  fputcsv($file_path,$result[$i]);
}
```

In order to stop this loop through 2nd ajax request I decided to use session variable called csv_creation. During creation, I start session using session_start() and $_SESSION['csv'] value will be start, and after clicking cancel its value will be end. By checking session variable each time inside the loop I will decide whether to continue writing or stop writing. Now my code is:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
{ 
  if ($_SESSION['csv'] === "end") {
    return "stop_csv";
  }
  fputcsv($file_path,$result[$i]);
}
```

My Problem is while clicking cancel I start the session again using session_start() and assign value as $_SESSION['csv'] = "end", but this session is not starting until the loop is completed which was started previously during creating csv. So I cannot stop the loop from execution.
Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem about stopping the loop?

Comment: Just don't start a new session, maybe?

Comment: Martin Zeitler - main page don't have any session. Request goes to new page so I have to start a new session each time for a request.

Comment: Well, it seems as if you already realize the problem; you need to keep the same session active, no matter the page; the one has nothing to do with the other; it's the purpose to carry data across pages - and so each page needs to maintain it. Triggering the export trough XHR might eventually be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You main problem is:

- One php script knows nothing about another.
- Php script starts with certain params and certain session, and it's not shared.

So, when you change session in new script, it doesn't affect old.

You can try another solution: store this in database or in special file (or flag file).

Comment: Yes i guess in my case I have to go with a flag file. Thanks for the explanation.